# ¿Cómo puedo especificar una ruta para manipular mi base de datos SQLite en Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, sqlite

Estoy empezando con SQLite y tengo el problema de que creé una base de datos con SQLite usando otro programa. He llevado esa base de datos a una carpeta assets de Android Studio pero no sé cómo indicarle al SQLiteOpenHelper que la busque en dicha carpeta. Al pulsar el botón me da el error IllegalArgumentsException. Este es el código que tengo

Main (aquí, al pulsar un botón se ejecuta la consulta:

```
                val db = DBHelper(this, "D:/AndroidStudioProjects/SQLite/app/src/main/assets/Preguntas.sqlite", null, 1)
                val dbAdmin = db.writableDatabase
                val pregunta = dbAdmin.rawQuery("Select Pregunta from Preguntas", null)

                db.close()
```

Esta es la clase que usa `SQLiteOpenHelper`:

```
    class DBHelper(context: Context, name: String, factory: CursorFactory?, version: Int): SQLiteOpenHelper(context, name, factory, version) {
    
        override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase) {
    
        }
    
        override fun onUpgrade(db: SQLiteDatabase?, oldVersion: Int, newVersion: Int) {
    
        }

}
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anteriormente podrías definir una ruta diferente a la predeterminada

```
   class DbHelper(context: Context) : SQLiteOpenHelper(context, "/mnt/sdcard/basesdedatos/example.db", null, 1) {
```

pero desde Android 10 si tu proyecto esta compilado con este sistema operativo o uno posterior no se puede crear un archivo fuera de la estructura destinada para la aplicación. La base de datos se creara en el almacenamiento interno y lo recomendado y ahora solo posible es que en la clase que extiende de `SQLiteOpenHelper` se defina su nombre.

```
val db = DBHelper(this, "Preguntas.sqlite", null, 1)
```